# Generate an ActiveRecord::Relation without any methods or using `all()`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-relation

Seemingly simple question.

I'm trying to build a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object from a model without using a method like `where()`. For example:

```
@people = Person

@people.where( status: 'active' ) if params(:active)
@people.where( is_smoker: true )  if params(:smokers)

return @people
```

You can see that if neither `active` or `smokers` is set in the params, @people is just the model, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

I could throw on `all` at the end of `return @people` but there must be a better way.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.scoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scoped) method:

```
@people = Person.scoped

@people.where( status: 'active' ) if params(:active)
@people.where( is_smoker: true )  if params(:smokers)

return @people
```

There is also the [`.unscoped` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) which basically does the same thing BUT ignores all the `default_scopes` defined.

---

**Rails 4: The method `.scoped` is deprecated**, see @FrederickCheung's answer

Comment: You answered it so fast I can't even accept it for another 3 minutes.

Comment: Ahah This is an easy question, must be quick to answer if I wanna get the rep' !

Answer (score 2):

On rails 3.x, `scoped` is the way to go. However it is deprecated in Rails 4 and removed in Rails 4.1

For rails 4.0 and higher, `all` just returns a scope, so you would instead write

```
@people = Person.all
@people.where( status: 'active' ) if params(:active)
@people.where( is_smoker: true )  if params(:smokers)

return @people
```

Comment: Really good to know for future versions of rails. I'm glad they're handling `all()` like that in 4.x.